# CSS - no showing popup

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

**CSS**

```
#help {
        width: 100%;
        .titletext {
                float: left;
                font-size: 150%;
        }
        .helpimage {
                float: right;
                position: relative;
        }
        .helpimage .tooltip-content {
                display: none;
                position: relative;
                bottom: 5%;
                left: 5%;
                right: 5%;
                background-color: red;
                padding: .5em;
                line-height: 1em;
        }
        .helpimage:hover .tooltip-content {
                display: block;
        }
}
```

**HTML/MEDIAWIKI**

```
<div id="help">
    <div class="titletext">Gene information</div>
    <div class="helpimage">[[File:Help.png]]
        <div class="tooltip-content">
            <p>Here it'll be a little explanation of this table.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With mouseover (above the image), it shows `Here it'll be a little explanation of this table`

Below the picture, **not** as a popup... Why is that behaving like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're nesting your css classes which is not allowed in CSS, unless you are maybe using a preprocessor?

your css should be like this I imagine:
http://jsfiddle.net/72o3x47p/2/

```
    #help {
            width: 100%;
    }
    .titletext {
            float: left;
            font-size: 150%;
    }
    .helpimage {
            float: right;
            position: relative;
    }
    .helpimage .tooltip-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute; /* change from relative to absolute */
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: red;
            padding: .5em;
            line-height: 1em;
    }
    .helpimage:hover .tooltip-content {
            display: block;
    }
```

Comment: The link you provide, text is shown below the picture, thus moving the image... It is not a popup...

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies!